# How many bytes will be written to memory if the cache has a write-back policy?

Tags: caching, memory-management, cpu-architecture

Array A contains 256 elements of 4 bytes each. Its first element is stored at physical address 4096.Array B contains
512 elements of 4 bytes each. Its first element is stored at physical address 8192. Assume that only arrays A and B
can be cached in an initially empty,physically addressed,physically tagged,direct-mapped, 2K-byte cache with an 8-byte
block size. The following loop is then executed.

for(i=0; i<256; i++)

A[i] = A[i] + B[2*i];

During the execution of the loop, how many bytes will be written to memory if the cache has a write-back policy ?

Given answer is **0**. Can someone explain how it is **0** ?

Comment: If you think it is something else, what and why?

Comment: Each array element of A is updated, so it should be written back to memory. So,it should be 256*4 bytes = 1024 bytes.

Comment: How (if at all) would your answer change if a write-through policy were used?  If it wouldn't change, what is the difference between these 2 policies?

Comment: In both cases, data will be written to cache, if at all it is written

Comment: But the question isn't asking about writes *to cache*, it's asking how many of those writes will go through the cache to memory.  i.e. how many stores the cache fails to filter out.  That's the whole point of a write-back cache instead of write-through.

Comment: yeah, dirty writes will always be written back to memory. Is the answer correct or is it something else ?

Comment: @PeterCordes Will  the answer be 256*4 = 1024 bytes since for each write, the cache becomes dirty and main memory is updated

Answer (score -1):

No of bytes written to memory = 256*4 = 1024 bytes since each element of array A is updated.So, cache becomes dirty for each element and main memory is updated for each element.

Comment: Eventually at some point, if no other writes to those locations happen first (in which case this data would never get written to memory).  But these stores don't have to wait for that, and don't *directly* cause any write-back.  This is the point of write-back caches instead of write-through.  For example, `mov [mem], eax` in a loop can run indefinitely without causing any memory traffic because it's constantly updating the same location in cache.